# Micrososoft One drive save files from django

Tags: python, django, onedrive

I have been trying to save my files to onedrive from django rest framework. I have tried following documentation of one drive sdk for python but nowhere it seemed to explain how to make it work th django. Documentation can be found at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python. I have made a drf model which is as follows:

```
class ReportVersionModel(models.Model):
  report_version_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  report = models.ForeignKey(ReportModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False, blank=False)
  file = models.FileField(upload_to='message/%Y/%m/%d/', max_length=100, blank=True)
```

what I need help is regarding how to use this model with the one drive sdk.

Comment: If it works with Python then it will work with Django, just put the code in your view, pushing the file to oneDrive from the received files.

Comment: Hi can you briefly explain what do you mean by putting code in view. I have created LC view and as far as I know we need to specify media_root and media_url specified in settings.py and then add + static in urls. py to save in local.Do we not need to change them?

Comment: Share the code you found for uploading files in Python and I'll tell you what I mean

Comment: To post files :  returned_item = client.item(drive='me', id='root').children['newfile.txt'].upload('./path_to_file.txt'). Here client was created earlier by one drive sdk.   To get file -download works as client.item(drive='me', id=id_of_file).download('./path_to_download_to.txt')